# $ \mathbb P ( A > t ) = \mathbb P ( A^{(1)} \wedge A^{(2)} > t ) $, why though? Dassios and Zhao 2013

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I'm reading a research paper saying :

$$ \mathbb P ( S_{k+1} > s ) = \exp \left( -  ( \lambda_{T_k^+} - a ) \frac{1- e^{- \delta s } }{\delta }  - as \right)   $$

$$= \exp \left( -  ( \lambda_{T_k^+} - a ) \frac{1- e^{- \delta s } }{\delta } \right )  \exp \left ( - as \right)$$
$$= \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(1)} > t ) * \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t )  $$ 
$$= \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t ) $$

$T_k^+$ is some time, intrinsically random, and $a$ as well as $\delta$ are some constants.
I don't understand yet the last equality. For the reason that if $ A^{(i)} $ is deterministic, then it shouldn't break down to the last equality.

What do you think ?

Those equations come from that paper : [ Dassios and Zhao 2013 ] https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ecp/1465315601

page 6, inside the proof of the algorithm. One can find the lines I copied in the last bit of the page. I really tried to put as many details as I could. I believe The two output random variables are independant because $S_k^{(2)}$ is constant for a given $s$.

Comment: What are $A$, $A^{(1)}$, and $A^{(2)}$? How do they relate to one another?

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I don't understand, is it important? I ve written those random varialbes as the functions $f$ and $g$, do you need any more information ? I wouldn't know how to give more information unless defining every term (which would make the post more complicated).

Comment: Well, you're claiming that their deterministic, and that the fact that they are should violate something, but I don't know how to begin to evaluate either of those statements without having any idea what those terms are.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I see; the variable "event omega from space Omega" was omitted. I'll add some details. What do you think now?

Comment: No, I still have no idea what's going on. I assume from the last equality that $S^{(1)}_{k+1}$ and $S^{(2)}_{k+1}$ are independent random variables? But I have no way of knowing if that is true or even reasonable.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery I m really sorry if that it is the case.                     S(2) is defined deterministicly, and I think it is true that all random variable is independant to a constant, right? I don't know what to write down more. And I don't know if I am allowed to join the reference from the research paper, I guess you're not supposed to do all the work for me neither. Can you imagine any information that I could add to the question? You mentioned independance and I am answering you that since the second one is constant for fixe time, they shall be independant.

Comment: I don't know how else to put this: I think you need to consider the perspective of someone who has not read the paper. Why not just link the paper, at least? Or copy the definitions of the relevant terms? There is simply no way we can help with what little you have provided.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery Sorry for that, I added the paper. I really tried my best to describe my problem in the simpliest way, apologies. Can you look at it again please ?

Comment: @MarineGalantin why do you say that the $S^2$ is deterministic? isn't it defined as the logarithm of an uniform distribution?

Comment: Thank you for posting the paper! The definitions we needed to be able to answer this question were on page 5 (under bullet 2.), and my guess appears to have been right -- they are independent random variables, as they're defined as functions of the (presumably independent) uniform variables $U_1, U_2$. I don't know why you're claiming they're deterministic, but it seems fairly clear that they aren't. (I'm happy to flesh this out a bit into an answer if this gets reopened.)

Comment: @AaronMontgomery what should I do if my post does not reopen :( ? I could delete the question and ask it again with the same content. What do you think?

Comment: @MarineGalantin Good question! I voted for it to be reopened but it looks like it may have gotten lost in the shuffle (and I think the number of reviewers who attend to such matters may be down due to world events). If you feel like your question has been answered, I'd say to just leave things as they are. But if you'd like a longer answer or some conversation about it, maybe try asking a question in meta.stackexchange.com asking folks to reconsider this question (and linking to it directly), since reposts are pretty heavily discouraged.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery you must have meant https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/ not [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345280) but despite that the desired result has been achieved ...

Comment: Oops, you're quite right! Thanks for the notice, I'll work on an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the relevant bit from the paper that explains what's going on:

> **Algorithm 3.1** (Univariate.) The simulation algorithm for one sample path of one-dimensional Hawkes process with exponentially decaying intensity $\{(N_t, \lambda_t)\}_{t \geq 0}$ conditional on $\lambda_0$ and $N_0 = 0$, with jumps-zie distribution $Y \sim G$ and $\overline K$ jump-times $\{T_1, T_2, \dots, T_{\overline K}\}$:
>
> 1. Set the initial conditions $T_0 = 0, \lambda_{T_0^{\pm}} = \lambda_0 > a$, $N_0 = 0$ and $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \dots, \overline K -1\}$.
> 2. Simulate the $(k+1)^{\text{th}}$ interarrival-time $S_{k+1}$ by
>      $$S_{k+1} = \begin{cases} S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k+1}^{(2)}, & D_{k+1} > 0 \\
>    S_{k+1}^{(2)}, & D_{k+1} < 0, \end{cases}$$
>      where
>      $$D_{k+1} = 1 + \frac{\delta\ln U_1}{\lambda_{T_k^+} - a}, \quad U_1 \sim U[0, 1],$$
>      and
>      $$S_{k+1}^{(1)} = - \frac 1 \delta \ln D_{k+1}, \quad S_{k+1}^{(2)} = - \frac 1 a \ln U_2, \quad U_2 \sim U[0, 1].$$

The crux is that $S_{k+1}^{(1)}$ is a function of $U_1$ (and some other variables), and $S_{k+1}^{(2)}$ is a function of $U_2$. Hence, $S_{k+1}^{(1)}$ and $S_{k+1}^{(2)}$ are indeed random variables, not deterministic.

Moreover: although it seems not to be explicitly stated, it appears that $U_2$ is independent of all other variables in the paper. Since $S_{k+1}^{(2)}$ depends only on it, and $S_{k+1}^{(1)}$ does not depend on it, the two variables are consequently independent of one another. This is what justifies the final equality in your original question.

---

Regarding the final equality: note that $\wedge$ denotes minimum, whence $S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t$ if and only if both terms individually are greater than $t$. Since they are independent, we have $\mathbb P(S_{k+1}^{(1)} > t \text{ and } S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t) = \mathbb P(S_{k+1}^{(1)} > t) \cdot \mathbb P(S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t)$.

Comment: thank you Aaron for your patience, it s much appreciated. Would you mind elaborating slightly about the probability bit " why is it linked to :" $$= \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(1)} > t ) * \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t )  $$ 
$$= \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t ) $$  maybe it is trivial, still I have no clue what's happening and why we have such equality.

Comment: Done! Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: Oh I see my problem was :
$$ \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(1)} > t  \text{ and, } S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t )  = \mathbb P ( S_{k+1}^{(1)} \wedge S_{k+1}^{(2)} > t ) $$ thank you !